# How do you install tplink tl-wn823n v2 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I have a problem with my tplink tl-wn823n v2 usb wifi adapter. I can not make it work on ubuntu 16.04.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the driver for the TL-WN823N V2 from TP Link's Website:
http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN823N.html#Driver

TL-WN823N(EU)_V2_160315_Linux is the Linux version of the driver on that page.